# S3 bucket access without keys (IAM role attached) in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I need a way to access my S3 bucket without secret and access keys, specifically in ruby. language.
I have tried to initialize this way`s3_obj = Aws::S3:Resource.new`.
None of the methods is suitable for my condition, I don't even know if it's possible.
SDK to be used: `aws-sdk-s3`

Comment: Have you made the bucket public? Are you sure that's what you wanted to do?

Comment: The bucket is private. I want to create aws client object without using the creds, and further access the objects inside it.

Comment: Also, since the IAM role is attached to the machine. I am able to access objects using was cli without using creds

Comment: Of course you're still using credentials; what do you think "attaching a role to the machine" does?! If you're using environment variables, for example, then you could reference these in your application's initialiser.